# Is checking if a value is present in a Python Set constant time?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, hashset

So I have read that Python's set is not like a list because it's actually based on hash tables. So if I check if a value is present is it constant time O(1) ?

Example:

```
def first_duplicate(arr):
    # Python set 
    holder = set()

    for item in arr:
        if item in holder:
            return item
        else:
            holder.add(item)

    return -1
```

Comment: `O(1)` is not possible because this means whatever element you select in the set becomes the target element, here `O(n)` is possible

Comment: @WasifHasan Oh, I see... but it's still faster than checking elements in a list, right?

Comment: It  is O(1) in average case and O(n) worst case. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @YuriGinsburg thank you very much! When would a worst case happen, though? Bad hash?

Comment: @Dio yes, as Python dicts and sets are hash-maps, given bad enough hash collision, all values could be in one bucket, which will lead to a linear search through it, resulting in O(n) complexity.

Intentionally putting all of values in one bucket is called [Hash flooding](https://131002.net/siphash/siphashdos_appsec12_slides.pdf) attack.

Comment: for loop takes `O(n)` time, (if item in holder) line takes `O(1)' because of set data type and adding to list also takes `O(1)` time, therefore, final time complexity is `O(n)` but hash tables wors cworst-case lookup time in most hash table schemes is O(n), If too many elements were hashed into the same key